# wrap with <Link> the function, but occurs an error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, function, hyperlink

```
const ContactsTableRow = ({ item, columns }: ContactsTableRowProps) => {
  return (
    <tr className={styles.body__tr}>
      {columns.map((columnItem: { name: string }, index: number) => {
        return (

        <Link to={'/contacts/99'}

              className={clsx(styles.action__title, styles.action__link)}>
            {if (columnItem.name === "id") {
          return (
          <td
          key={index}
          className={clsx([styles.body__td, styles.body__action])}
          >
          <p className={clsx(styles.action__title, styles.action__link)}>
        {item[`${columnItem.name}`]}
          </p>
          </td>
          );
          }
            }

        </Link>

        )
```

i want to go to an another page with click, and i wrapped this with , but there occurs an error: } expected
TS1109: Expression expected.!

Comment: JSX 101: you can only interpolate _expressions_, not statements.

Answer (score -1):

```
{column.Item === "id" && {
      return (
      <td
      key={index}
      className={clsx([styles.body__td, styles.body__action])}
      >
      <p className={clsx(styles.action__title, styles.action__link)}>
    {item[`${columnItem.name}`]}
      </p>
      </td>
      );
      }
```

[Conditional Rendering in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html)